# How to do a date formula in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have to do a query that increments automatically the date year by year. For example I use this formula:

`=INDEX(query('Scheda Intervento'!C3:K14;"select sum (K) where (F >= date '2013-01-01' and F <= date '2013-01-31' and C = '" & A3 &"')");2;1)`

But every year I have to change the date in 2014 , 2015 etc.

Comment: Did my solution with the `INDEX` function work?

Comment: Perhaps you can mark it as such. Read [ask] on how to mark a answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
=INDEX(query('Scheda Intervento'!C3:K14;"select sum (K) where (F >= date '"&YEAR(NOW())&"-01-01' and F <= date '"&YEAR(NOW())&"-01-31' and C = '" & A3 &"')");2;1)
```

I used the function YEAR(NOW())